# Problema no meu sistema de notificações

Tags: android

A questão é que estou com problemas no meu sistema de notificações, pois ele ler um xml, e salva o id com sharedPreferences, então na hora de verificar o xml novamente ele compara o id salvo com o id vindo do xml atual toda vez que for verificar, se for diferente notifica, o problema é que as vezes está notificando mesmo sem eu atualizar nada no xml, vejam como está o codigo:

public class NotificacaoService extends Service {

```
SharedPreferences settings;
String idSalvo;
ItemXml item;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefXml";

public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
     item = new ItemXml();

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

}
```

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

```
    verificaNotificacao();
    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

public void verificaNotificacao() {
        if (verificaConexao()) { //se tiver conexão 
            getXml(); // vai carregar o xml salvando o id atual
            readValue(); // vai ler o valor que tem salvo no dispotivo atual para comparar

```
        if (!idSalvo.equals(item.getId())) { //compara os dois
            idSalvo = item.getId();// se for diferente ele iguala
            gerarNotificacao(); // e notifica
            saveValue(); //depois salva o novo fa
            // salva o valor atual
        }
    }
    stopSelf(); // mata o serviço
}


/*
 * Metodo que vai carregar os items do xml atual
 */

public void getXml() {
    try {
        // Cria o leitor de RSS
        XmlReader rssReader = new XmlReader(
                "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/teste.xml");
        item.setId(rssReader.getItems().get(0).getId()); // item recebe o id do xml atual

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("notificações", e.getMessage());
    }
}

/*
 * Salvando valor do id com sharedPreferences
 */
public void saveValue() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("idXml", idSalvo);

        // Confirma a gravação dos dados
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Notificações", e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Vai ler o valor salvo no dispositivo
public void readValue() {

    idSalvo = settings.getString("idXml", "");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, era porque o valor la do xml estava vindo nulo quando o servidor caia, então esqueci de tratar o valor nulo e ele notificava, mas agora tratei isso.

Answer (score 0):

A documentçao Android indica, sobre SharedPreferences "This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed)".
Tradução: "Estes dados persistem entre sessões, mesmo que sua aplicação é morto."

Então, deve ter um outro problema.

URL: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: mudei o tema da pergunta, se puder me ajudar ficarei grato.